# Selenium Select By Visible text fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my setup is the following:

I use Java8 with selenium webdriver for IE11.

I have an application of which I can't change the source, but I can see it.

when using xpath to select a specific dropdown in a table in an iframe in a popup, I can read it's attributes and tagname, but i can't read it's text using getText().

What's more, when I use

```
Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByVisibleText(value);
```

it does not work, nor the variant with

```
Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByIndex(valueOf);
```

However, when I do a simple reproduction, on a really basic html page with a select, I can read the text in the options.
This html page is loosely based on the popup page, where this specific dropdown is nothing fancy either.

Anyone has/had the same issue before?
all help appreciated

Comment: Relevant HTML ?

Comment: Don't have a reproduction, that's why I'm struggling to solve it..